# Python child instance property appears to be overridden by parent property

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instance

I'm in the process of learning Python 3 and writing conceptual bits of code to aid my understanding. I hit a problem with a simple class inheritance example where an instance variable from the child class appears to be overridden by the parent variable.

I've played around with the following code in various forms and have simplified it for the purpose of this question. I can't figure out why the Child object's own `__str__()` method is referring to the `name` property of the Parent when I am using `self.name` inside the Child class to refer to the `name` property of the Child (it's as if `self.name` is replaced with `super().name`).

```py
class Parent():

    """ Parent class that will take a name or default to 'Default Parent'.
    """

    def __init__(self, name="Default Parent"):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Parent: I am {self.name}'

class Child(Parent):

    """ Child class inheriting from Parent class
    """

    def __init__(self, name="Default Child"):
        # setting self.name to the name passed in during Child instantiation
        self.name = name
        # not passing self.name so parents's self.name will be defaulted to "Default Parent"
        super().__init__() 

    def __str__(self):
        # self.name prints "Default Parent"
        # The property self.name in Child appears to be overridden.
        # Thought self.name here refers to the instant variable belonging to the instance of Child and not super().name.
        return f'Child: I am {self.name}'
```

I've tested this as follows:

```
p1 = Parent("Parent 1")
c1 = Child("Child 1")
print(p1)
print(c1)
```

I expected these results back:

```
Parent: I am Parent 1
Child: I am Child 1
```

Instead, I got these back:

```
Parent: I am Parent 1
Child: I am Default Parent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `super().__init__()` after you set the `self.name` in `Child`.  This is overwriting the property.  Instead, pass the name parameter to the parent init.

```
class Child(Parent):

    """ Child class inheriting from Parent class
    """

    def __init__(self, name="Default Child"):
        super().__init__(name=name)
```

Comment: Hiya. Thanks for this. I realise explicitly passing the name to the parent would set the Parent name. Does this mean the Child class property "name" cannot exist in isolation to the Parent property "name"? Or put another way, if name was a **method** in Parent, and name was also a **method** in Child, invoking the child's name method would override the parent's name method right - it'll never be the case that calling self.name() within Child would invoke the parent's name method. So why is it different for properties/variables?

Comment: You created two properties 'name': One in Parent, the other in Child. In your case however, 'name' should probably exist _only_ in Parent. Another 'name' in Child is needlessly redundant and is overwritten by super().__init__(name=name) anyway. If you really want a separate 'name' in Child, don't call super().__init__().

Comment: That's made perfect sense and I can now see the redundant nature in the design. I'm still learning the Python way of doing things, and all your answers have helped me progress further. Thank you.